# Deprecate tables in EF Core without removing them from the database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, database-migration

Due to changed business requirements I need to completely re-model some parts of the system, which will result in significant DB schema changes. I want to keep the data pre-model-changes in the database (e.g. for audit purposes), but **I don't need it to be accessible using EF Core**. I would like to keep the original tables names since they pretty accurately describe the data kept in them, but I would like to avoid however is updating the schema for existing data which will make it incomplete and partial. What are the best practices regarding it?

I had couple of ideas in my mind:

1. Rename the entities, underlying DB tables, indexes etc. so they are e.g. prefixed with '_legacy' / 'Legacy', mark services using them as obsolete, move them to some legacy namespace (in code) and then add new tables with target schema but the same names as existing ones (prior renaming).
2. Move/copy the tables with the data to another legacy DB schema, where they cannot be accessed by EF Core, make necessary changes in the models, wipe existing data (since now it has backup in the other DB schema).
3. Do not do anything specific, update models to the required state, just backup the database prior applying the migrations, wipe all the data during migration. But in this scenario I cannot access this data in the database without using the backup, so it's not very handy.

Are there any better ways to achieve the described outcome? Or am I trying to solve th wrong problem? Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Moving table to other schema is an option. But removing a DbSet with EF code First migrations wants to drop the table, so I have to keep the DbSet/ table in the DbContext.
I use EF 6.4.4 , may EFCore 2 har more options. I tried to ignore the entity